# Compare two datetime in angular (one is fetch from mysql database and one is node server)

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, datetime

I want to compare datetime in angular.
for example i have two following date

**Registation Start Date : 2019-08-26 12:24:21** from mysql database
I am using Node server as backend

**Current Date from node server**

```
serverDate :new Date();
```

I have converted above **serverDate** to mysql format using following code

```
newServerDate : new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
```

i have send **newServerDate** to angular which i have used as front end. In angular i have compare above two date as follows

```
var DateFormMysql = 2019-08-26 12:24:21
var DateFromNode  = 2019-08-26 12:24:21
if(DateFromNode <= DateFormMysql ){
console.log('in if');
}
```

I am stuck on above code, i am not able to compare two datetime variables

P.S : i want to mention here the datetime i get from node server is not correct
For example when i was writting this question,i get following datetime when i console new Date() in angular
**Tue Aug 27 2019 13:27:28 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**
when i console same new Date() in node server i get following result
**2019-08-27T08:00:31.301Z**

Dont know where i am getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use Moment.js : https://momentjs.com/

The package on npm is here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

It's a really powerful library that allows you to compare dates.

This way you could do :

```
import * as moment from 'moment

moment(DateFormMysql).isAfter(moment(DateFromNode)) //=> true/false
```

Comment: u are saying that i should use moment.js in angular

Comment: We are using it, and it's pretty good ! Furthermore, you can use the npm package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend date-fns because you can import only those functions that you need. Maybe moment.js ha change but it used be very big and you needed to import everything